# PHP switch/case json_encode

Tags: php, json

I am quite confused on this one. While using the switch/case below, if I echo out case 1 my results are as follows:

```
Metal Cover (300)
Plexi (300)
Flat Cover (200)
Paper Cover (250)
```

When I echo out the json_encode it returns the following:

```
{"300":"Plexi (300)","200":"Flat Cover (200)","250":"Paper Cover (250)"}
```

Why am I losing one of my rows? - thanks

**Code**

```
$type = 'cover';
    $stt = 1;
    $productId = 81;

        $results = array();
        switch ($type) {
        case "cover":
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                                    FROM albumcover 
                                    WHERE productId = '{$productId}'
                                ");
            $results[0] ="None";
            switch ($stt){
                case 1:
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                        echo $results[$row['price2']] = $row['coverupgrade'] . ' (' . $row['price2'] . ')<br>';
                    }
                break;
                case 2:
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                        $results[$row['price3']] = $row['coverupgrade'] .' (' . $row['price3'] . ')';
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                        $results[$row['price4']] = $row['coverupgrade'] .' (' . $row['price4'] . ')';
                    }
                    break;
                default :
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                        $results[$row['price1']] = $row['coverupgrade'].' ('.$row['price1'].')';
                    }
                    break;
            }
            echo json_encode($results);
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: agreed, when they pay me to fix that, consider it done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loosing a row because you are using the value of `$row['pricex']` as the key, and you have two rows where the price is the same, so the later value overwrites the first. In order to transmit the data effectively you will need to change the structure of the JSON:

```
$type = 'cover';
$stt = 1;
$productId = 81;

$results = array();
switch ($type) {
    case "cover":
        $query = mysql_query("
            SELECT * 
            FROM albumcover 
            WHERE productId = '{$productId}'
        ");
        $results[0] ="None";
        switch ($stt){
            case 1:
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                    $results['data'][] = array('price'=>$row['price2'], 'coverupgrade' => $row['coverupgrade'] . ' (' . $row['price2'] . ')<br>';
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                    $results['data'][] = array('price'=>$row['price3'], 'coverupgrade' => $row['coverupgrade'] . ' (' . $row['price3'] . ')<br>';
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                    $results['data'][] = array('price'=>$row['price4'], 'coverupgrade' => $row['coverupgrade'] . ' (' . $row['price4'] . ')<br>';
                }
                break;
            default:
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                    $results['data'][] = array('price'=>$row['price1'], 'coverupgrade' => $row['coverupgrade'] . ' (' . $row['price1'] . ')<br>';
                }
                break;
        }
        break;
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

Given the data you show, this should output:

```
{
  "0": "none",
  "data": [
    {
      "price": "300",
      "coverupgrade": "Metal Cover (300)"
    },
    {
      "price": "300",
      "coverupgrade": "Plexi (300)"
    },
    {
      "price": "200",
      "coverupgrade": "Flat Cover (200)"
    },
    {
      "price": "250",
      "coverupgrade": "Paper Cover (250)"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help on this. I am getting the following return on the json_encode - {"0":"None","data":["Array (300)
","Array (300)
","Array (200)
","Array (250)
"]}

Comment: Array ( [0] => None [data] => Array ( [0] => Array (300)
[1] => Array (300)
[2] => Array (200)
[3] => Array (250)
) )

Comment: @Bungdaddy OK, I have removed the `echo` statements from the code above (which I didn't notice until just now). They would have been breaking the output anyway, I think they may be causing something to get cast to a string somehow - which I won't fully understand until I've had a play around with it.

Answer (score 9):

Metal cover and Plexi have the same key (300). Keys must be unique, so the latter overwrites the first one.

If you want to store multiple values for a single key, you have to use another array (not sure if this is what you want though):

```
$results[$row['priceX']][] = $row['coverupgrade'].' ('.$row['priceX'].')';
```

JSON encoded it will look like this:

```
{
  "300":["Metal Cover (300)", "Plexi (300)"],
  "200":["Flat Cover (200)"],
  "250":["Paper Cover (250)"]
}
```